# Bessel equation of zero order of second kind using the frobenius method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While studying power series and special functions in my textbook I encountered a problem which asked me to find the second independent solution besides the one from the frobenius power series (which in this case transformed to a regular power series soln as the order is zero).

Using a theorem given in my textbook that states the second solution is of the type
 $y_1 logx + x^p \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$
I substituted this into the zero order bessel ODE and after multiple tries I am missing the $c_n$ by factor of 2.
Note here while substituting I took

$p=0$(obviously)
$c_0=0$ for simplicity.

Note:- I do realise that in further discussions on special functions there might be many other ways to evaluate the other solution near zero but currently I would appreciate solution the above type.
Edit1:-Solved

Edit 2:- the answer involved substituting above form of solution into the zero order bessel ode finding a recursion equation for coefficients that pointed to odd coefficients being zero since $a1=0$ and the first solution is a frobenius series has only even powers of x. Then general Induction leads to the correct solution of second type.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for solutions to 
$$
xy''+y'+xy=0
$$
as the $n=0$ case of the general Bessel equation $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-n^2)y=0$.

The coefficients for the power series satisfy ($a_n=0$ for $n<0$)
$$
[n(n-1)+n]a_n+a_{n-2}=0
$$
so that with $a_0=1$ one gets the solution
$$
y_1(x)=1-\frac14x^2+\frac1{64}x^4\mp\dots
$$
Order reduction tells us that the second solution is of the form $y_2=uy_1$ where
$$
x(y_1u''+2y_1'u')+y_1u'=0\implies \frac{u''}{u'}=-\frac{2xy_1'+y_1}{xy_1}
\\
\implies \ln|u'|=-\ln|xy_1^2|+C\qquad\text{(set $C=0$)}
\\
u'=\frac{1}{xy_1^2}=\frac1x+\frac12x+\dots
$$
so that
$$
y_2=\ln(x)y_1+\frac12x+\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_{2k+1}x^{2k+1}
$$
Does that conform with your solution?

Comment: Well I was looking for a specific kind of solution which when I got , I edited the question however  I am thankful for your solution.

Comment: In the question you were missing details on what you exactly got, the main steps how you got there and what the textbook solution was. Each of those could have been incorrect. Without saying what was wrong the answer only could be that general.

Comment: You're absolutely right... I have edited the question accordingly.